# URL Change .htaccess Code Not Working

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url, wampserver

I want to change:

```
localhost/article.php?id=bryan
```

To simply:

```
localhost/article/bryan
```

And if it's something like:

```
localhost/article.php?id=Mark%20Henry%20is%20Drawing
```

I need that to change that to just:

```
localhost/article/mark-henry-drawing
```

A fellow here gave me this code to use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^article/([^/]*)$ /article.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Everyone is saying that this should do the trick, but I'm still getting internal server errors every time I type in:

```
localhost/article/bryan
```

I'm using WAMP server if that helps at all, the following code is my entire `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# Removes the .php extension from pages
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]

# Cleans up the PHP URL of all pages on website
RewriteRule ^article/([^/]*)$ /article.php?id=$1 [L]
```

I don't know what else to try.

Comment: _“but I'm still getting internal server errors”_ – then lock into the server’s error log!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the problem with your current `.htaccess` is that its going into a loop causing the internal server error.

To make what you wish work you need to capture the URL at the request and redirect it, and then internally redirect it back:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect /article.php?id=bryan to /article/bryan
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+article\.php\?id=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /article/%1? [R=302,L]

# Internally forward /article/bryan to /article.php?id=bryan
RewriteRule ^article/([^/]+)/?$ /article.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
```

However there is no easy way to convert `%20` into spaces or `-` you will have to work that out from your system.

Comment: So what do you mean by work it out on my system? Is there no universal way to do it?

Comment: @user3310212 not with .htaccess they will be overcomplicated and expensive to the point of not being worth using as it will put a big load on the server, you will have to either convert it on your code side to make it dash on the link or some other way.